# Task class - multiple waits and exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

usually I encapsulated a task as follows:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        func_can_throw_exception();
    }, token).
ContinueWith
    ((task) =>
        {
            try
            {
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                ae.Handle((x) =>
                {
                    //handle
                    return true;
                });
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        });
```

The questions is what happens if I wait (`t.Wait();`) on this task in a seperate thread (for example the GUI thread). Is this allowed. If there is an exception during task execution, how is this handled?

Comment: Instead of rethrowing the exception, check `task.IsFaulted` and then call `task.Exception.Handle()`. Or use `async/await` to simplify the entire process

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it like that. The better way is:

```
Task.Run(() => {
    func_can_throw_exception();
})
.ContinueWith(task => {
    do_something_with(task.Exception);
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

But in the code you provided `task.Wait()` won't block since `ContinueWith` only fires *after* the task is finished.

In the general case, `task.Wait()` will block the current thread until the task is finished. If the task fails, then `Wait` will throw an `AggregateException`. But using `Wait` can cause deadlocks if you're not careful. It's best to use continuations in TPL code.

Comment: These are threads which are generally runs through the whole program life time (image grabbing from a camera thread). At FormClosed I want to make sure all task are done before closing.

Comment: I see... Then I guess you could indeed use `Task.WaitAll` if you make *extra* sure you won't get deadlocks. Also, better give that function a timeout so you don't hang indefinitely.

Comment: If you do this, the final `Task` (returned by `ContinueWith()`) will be canceled if the original `Task` succeeds. I don't think such behavior was intended.

Comment: @svick I suppose you're talking about the `WaitAll` call - in that case you're definitely right, the wait should be performed on the original tasks. (use something like `var t = Task.Run(...); t.ContinueWith(...); return t;`)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That returns a failed `Task` even though the exception was (presumably) already handled by the continuation. I *think* the intention of the code in the question is to return a successful `Task` whether the original `Task` failed or not.

Comment: @svick Oh OK I see your point. But there's not enough context to know for sure, so OP would need to clarify that. OP: if that's the case, you could chain an empty continuation: `.ContinueWith(t => {})`

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to `Wait` on tasks since it blocks the calling thread as opposed to `await` which waits asynchronously. It's espically dangerous to block the GUI thread since it can very quickly lead to deadlocks.

You are handling any exception internally so unless `Handle` throws an exception `t.Wait()` would not throw any exceptions.

What you should be doing is using `async-await`:

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() => func_can_throw_exception());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: He's also using `Wait` on an already completed task. He can simply use `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`.

Comment: In this case the call to `Wait` occurs inside the continuation so there is no blocking. It's just bad form, as he could check `Faulted` and use `Handle` instead of rethrowing the original exception before handling it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos since he asked about `t.Wait();` and the result task is named `t` while the inner task is named `task` I assume he's not asking about the inner `Wait()`. Especially if the GUI thread is mentioned.

Comment: Yes. The task is something like an image grabber thread which lifetime is the entire program lifetime. When the user closes the Form I want to make sure all threads are done before finally closing the application.

Comment: @I3arnon didn't notice it, that's a weird way to use a task

Comment: @user3701958 the framework already supports this scenario. Use a CancellationTokenSource to create and pass a CancellationToken to each thread and have them either check it or subscribe to its events. When the main form closes, signal its completion.